# ALTER TABLE problems

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I have a problem, I want to add a foreign key (email) into the table `bericht`.

Email references to email in `vrijwilliger`, email is a `varchar(80)`.

```
ALTER TABLE bericht
ADD(
FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES vrijwilliger(email));
```

Error message:

> #1005 - Can't create table '.\c5g4westpopintranet#sql-1494_145.frm' (errno: 150)

I don't get it, hope you can help me.

First table

```
CREATE TABLE bericht(
berichtID int(8),
onderwerp varchar(255),
datum date,
tijd time,
inhoudbericht,
email varchar(80),
PRIMARY KEY(berichtID),
FOREIGN KEY(email) REFERENCES vrijwilliger(email));
```

Second table

```
 CREATE TABLE vrijwilliger(
 vrijwilligerID int(8),
 email varchar(80),
 Primary key(vrijwilligerID));
```

Comment: Is `vrijwilliger(email)` the `PRIMARY KEY` - or does it have a `UNIQUE` index on it?

Comment: can you show the schema of the two tables?

Comment: Just check the data type and size for email is same in both the tables.

Comment: Run `show create table berich` and the same for the other table. Update you question with the results.

Comment: Just to be sure.. Did you use the SQL above to create the bericht table? If you did, it already has a foreign key called email.. If not, then the problem is probably missing indexes (you'll need ond for both bericht.email and vrijwilliger.email..

Comment: You did two mistakes in your query.... 1. You didn't define datatype for the field inhoudbericht in bericht table 2. Unique Key is the next candidate to be referenced in another child after Primary key. since email field of vrijwilliger is not a primary key so it should be Unique Key so that it could be referenced in bericht table.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Query to alter table

```
ALTER TABLE bericht ADD CONSTRAINT email FOREIGN KEY(email) REFERENCES vrijwilliger(email) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL;
```

Syntax for Alter table

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

Refer

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
```

Comment: It gives SQL-query:

ALTER TABLE bericht ADD CONSTRAINT email FOREIGN KEY ( email ) REFERENCES vrijwilliger( email ) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL

MySQL retourneerde: Documentatie
#1005 - Can't create table '.\c5g4westpopintranet\#sql-1494_176.frm' (errno: 150)

Comment: Have you crate the table vrijwilliger before bericht table

Comment: Try like this when you create a table
CONSTRAINT email_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES vrijwilliger(email) ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: w8 in vrijwilliger the email varchar(80) is not a primary key... it must right?

Answer (score -1):

Try below query, it will work for you

```
CREATE TABLE `vrijwilliger` (  
vrijwilligerID INT(8),  
email VARCHAR(80),  
PRIMARY KEY(vrijwilligerID),
UNIQUE KEY (email)
);

CREATE TABLE bericht( 
berichtID INT(8), 
onderwerp VARCHAR(255), 
datum DATE, 
tijd TIME, 
inhoudbericht INT(8), 
email VARCHAR(80), 
PRIMARY KEY(berichtID), 
FOREIGN KEY(email) 
REFERENCES vrijwilliger(email));
```

Comment: I get the error that the table bericht can't be dropped.

#1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails